# How can I build a transparent shape with colored background

Tags: android, view, android-drawable, shapes

I need this:

[image: The white must be transparent(not blue)]

the white must be transparent

if I use this shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<size android:height="32dp"
    android:width="16dp"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"
    />
<corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
/>
```

inside of

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yyy"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

I get a blue rectangle (because the color under the transparent shape is blue)

How can I get the shape transparent so I will see the color behind the ImageView?

Comment: cannot you use a regular png `Bitmap`?

Comment: haha, yes!! that was so simple, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Write code into your color:

```
<color name="transparent">#10000000</color>
```

and also use `<solid android:color="@color/transparent">`